# Fingering your own anus for masturbation purposes

Tags: halal-haram, sex, masturbation

I'm a 19 year old male, who tried my best to quit masturbation by various techniques from keeping myself busy. However, I definitely intend to quit and the only way to do that quick as I researched is by getting married.

Moving on, my masturbation is different from other people's masturbation as I lay down and apply pressure using my right hand on my penis. I read about this and it's bad masturbate by pressure as it could be a problem in the future so I tried quitting. however I failed and decided to masturbate like a normal human being so I researched about this and found out many techniques to ejaculate while watching porn one of which is fingering your asshole. Unfortunately, at that very moment I tried it and felt a lot of guilt and I still do and I ask Allah for forgiveness I feel it's not under my control to quit even though I wish I could.

Long story short is masturbating by inserting one finger in your anus while the other your right is rubbing down your penis okay?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour], checking our [help] and reading [ask] to learn more about this site.

Comment: Note that you may find related questions on this site some are linked at the right hand of this page. Also note that many Muslim scholars consider masturbation as a haraam act. And only a few allow it under defined circumstances. So masturbation is considered as a sin from which one should repent, therefore asking on techniques or how to perform it seems to me unlawful as the act itself is more or less condemned! On the other hand when it comes to sexual pleasure (with the spouse) there are only a few limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Its a small sin not big sin 
Its unliked buddy
U cant say for somethint is haram when is not mentioned in Quran and in naration of prophet  slw
Lot of scolars say is unliked and sin not big sin
We have to try to avoid as much as we can we are human and desires sometimes are uncontrolled when goes.extreme because it might send in adultry if you dont ejaculate
If u think you will commit adultery scolars say is better to.ejacuate but not to last and have deep feeling just relase the desire and repenr inshaAllah Allah will forgive
Thats why prophet slw never mention the ejaculation part because sometimes when you not married sometimes even u fast u cant stop it brother its hard and sometimes make.person crazy have no choise but to ejaculate or get maried as soon as he can
I dont advice you inserting fingers in anus maybe you feel better orgasm but anus is dirty you might hurt andus and get bowl syndrome you end up all your life with diapers like little.kids
Be carefull
But if you have prostate problem.than is healthy to massage orostate inside anus but even after that u have male prostste masages toys special for prostate
Asalamu alaikum